# Can we set QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE for a specific database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As per the [link](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#impact-of-changing-the-parameter) the parameter `QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE` can be set for a given session by including within the connection string.

Our application needs to use this setting and we require this to be set at Database/account level by default

Does Snowflake allow this setting to be done at account/database level?

Answer (score 2):

With the ACCOUNTADMIN Role, you can set the this parameter at the account level with the following statement:

alter account set QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE = TRUE;

I would stress that you examine the warnings in the documentation you reference in the question closely.

Comment: In addition, if you wish this to only be for the application user, you can set this for just the user that the application is using.